# how to solve this scanner method error in java?

Tags: java

not working...
how remove errors..
please help me
what to do

it is give me error in scanner scan method something
i cant able to solve this...

how to use this scanner class

```
import java.util.*;

public class A
{

  class Student
  {

    int i,id,age;
    int m[]=new int[3];
    int tot=0,per;
    String name;


    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    Student(int id,String name,int age)
    {
      this.id=id;
      this.name=name;
      this.age=age;
    }

    public void getMarks()
    {
      System.out.println("Enter UR marks-- ");

      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        System.out.print("\n Enter Marks For Sub "+i);
        m[i]=scan.nextInt();
        tot=tot+m[i];
      }
    }

    void display()
    {
      System.out.println("ID-- "+id);
      System.out.println("Name-- "+name);
      System.out.println("Age-- "+age);
      System.out.println("Total-- "+tot);
      System.out.println("Percentage-- "+(per/i));

    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Student s1=new Student(101,"jay",20);
    s1.getMarks();
    s1.display();
  }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
import java.util.*;

class Student {

int i, id, age;
int m[] = new int[3];
int tot = 0, per;
String name;



Student(int id, String name, int age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    }

public void getMarks() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter UR marks-- ");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("\n Enter Marks For Sub " + i);
        m[i] = scan.nextInt();
        tot = tot + m[i];
      }
   }

void display() {
    System.out.println("ID-- " + id);
    System.out.println("Name-- " + name);
    System.out.println("Age-- " + age);
    System.out.println("Total-- " + tot);
    System.out.println("Percentage-- " + (per / i));

    }

}

public class A {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student s1 = new Student(101, "jay", 20);
    s1.getMarks();
    s1.display();
    }

}
```

Some tips :
1) Never declare a **class as a member of other class** unless the needs are so. (As you did, `class Student` **inside** `class A`.
2) Declare instantiate the `Scanner` object **inside the method** where you want to use it. Declaring it as a **class member** doesn't serve any purpose.
3) Always **close** scanner after the use. i.e. `scan.close()`

Visit these links :

1. [When to use nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)
2. [Using Scanner in java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm)

Comment: try to import only Scanner class.. by writing `import java.util.Scanner`
the code which i have pasted above is a working one coz I've tried running it